# Android: CallStaticVoidMethod gets called only once

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have a JNI code and I am trying to call a static method in Java.

The OnLoad in JNI looks like below

```
extern "C" jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved) {
        JNIEnv *e;

        mJvm = jvm;

        if (jvm->GetEnv((void**) &e, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
                ALOGE("Error getting Env var");
                return JNI_ERR;
        }

        ALOG_ASSERT(env, "Could not retrieve the env!");

        app = e->FindClass("xyz");
        updateService = e->GetStaticMethodID(app, "updatestatus", "(I)V");

        jniRegisterNativeMethods(e, "xyz",
                                 Methods, NELEM(Methods));

        return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

I have following global variables

```
JavaVM *mJvm;
jclass app;
jmethodID updateHDToService;
```

The callback where I am trying to call the Java method looks like this

```
JNIEnv *e;
if (!mIsListenerAttached) {
        if (mJvm->AttachCurrentThread(&e, NULL) != JNI_OK) {
                ALOGE("Error attaching native thread to java");
                mIsListenerAttached = false;
                return;
        }
        ALOGI("Aattached native thread to java");
        mIsListenerAttached = true;
}

e->CallStaticVoidMethod(app, updateHDToService, radioContext->signalStat);
```

The static method in Java is called successfully only one time. Next time the same callback is executed it does not call the java method.

What am I doing wronG?

Comment: There obviously is some class which has a member `bool mIsListenerAttached`. Your code expects that there would be a single instance of this member per (native) thread. But if you intend to call `xyz.uodatestatus()` Java void method more than from one native thread, you probably need to keep the `mIsListenerAttached` in thread local storage (aka TLS) or use an alternative mechanism. _And don't forget to call `mJvm->detachCurrentThread()` before the native thread exits._

Comment: @AlexCohn I have `bool mIsListenerAttached` as a global variable in my JNI file. I don't have any class in my JNI. This itself could be a problem, not sure. I am new to JNI. How do I find out if there are multiple native threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html. You don't need the protection variable,  [Calling AttachCurrentThread on an already-attached thread is a no-op.](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#threads).

But don't forget to call `mJvm->detachCurrentThread()` before the native thread exits!

Comment: When a thread is [created](http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=pthread_create), it runs what is known as "thread function". In the end, it either calls [ptherad_exit()](http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=pthread_exit), or simply returns. That's the end of thread life. If the thread was attached to JVM, it should get explicitly detached before it finishes in either of the above manners. You can actually detach a thread immediately after you have called the Java callback, but if this happens too often, the overhead may be significant.

Comment: Another dumb question. I am not starting any thread explicitly. I am building a JNI library and loading this library in the Java code of app.

Comment: I was under impression that you use a big 3<sup>rd</sup>-party library as a black box, and it could possibly start its own threads. If this is not the case, and all execution paths start in the Java app, you can probably forget about all these `AttachCurrentThread()` and `DetachCurrentThread()`.

Comment: I am using a third partly library which is creating threads when I call their APIs. The place where I am trying to call a Java method is inside a callback I register with the third party API.  In this case where should I detach thread?

Comment: As I suggested, you can detach a thread immediately after you have called the Java callback. If this happens too often, the overhead may be significant. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html explains how you can register a function which will be automagically executed when the pthread gets destroyed.

Comment: Thanks @alex-Cohn for all the suggestions. The Java method I was calling from JNI was trying to update some UI controls in Activity. When I removed that part of code from the Java method, I don't see this issue of method being called only once. Any suggestions on how Do I update Activity from a service in Android

Comment: You should manipulate UI only from the main thread. The easiest way is to call `runOnUiThread()` from your Java callback.

Comment: Thanks @alex-cohn, I am calling a service API from JNI, so using intents to update UI/Activity and it works well.